# How can I specify a custom mapping between certain types in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I need to present all DateTime values as local, but store them as UTC. How can I tell AutoMpapper than when it maps MappedViewModel to EntityBase it must convert dates from local to UTC, and then vice versa?

I already know how to do the conversion, so this question applies only to the mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you do this with a [Custom Type Converter](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters)?  When registered, it appears they are global in scope, so in theory, you could apply it to all DateTime types.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I could apply a type convertor to classes of a certain base, not just globally?